# Toggle in javascript - Div toggle possibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i want is that making an div toggle. Visible it or not.

this is my div

```
<div id="kullanici_ara" style="display:none;">
<form action="kullanicilar.php" method="get">
<label>Aramak istediğiniz kullanıcının adını giriniz</label><br />
<input type="text" name="ara"/>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="nick" checked="checked">Pasaj Adı</input>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="id" />Id</input>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="name" />Ad-Soyad</input>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="email" />E-posta</input>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="city" />Şehir</input>
<br /><br />
<label>Kullanıcıları puanlarına göre büyükten->küçüğe sıralamak için seçiniz.</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" value="puan" name="puansort"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Ara" />
</form><br /><br />
</div>
```

Is there a way to toggle div according to id ? I mean a have a code like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Is there a way to write above code a id ?

Comment: Where is the button in the HTML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#kullanici_ara").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

See: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNfQB/)

Keep in mind that every button will now toggle the div with id `#kullanici_ara`. Maybe you want to specify a certain button with an id. Something like:

```
<button id='clickbutton'>Toggle div</button>
```

And:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clickbutton").click(function(){
    $("#kullanici_ara").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

See: [ID-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the syntax is `$('#elementId')...`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#kullanici_ara").toggle(); // # + the div Id 
  });
});
```

You should read the [selectors section](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in jQuery API website

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   $("#kullanici_ara").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is not what he asked for. anyway how would click the `<div>` again when it's hidden??

Comment: This will not work, this will toggle the visibility on every click in the div. Also if you click in one of the input.